# Lazy Cache mocking GetorAddasync()

Tags: mocking, xunit, lazycache

My service code is below:

`var cachedLatestVersion = await _cache.GetOrAddAsync("latestVersion", latestVersion, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(24));`

I have tried to mock the IAppache interface and set up a value for the GetOrAddAsync method but an error occurred

`_cacheMock.Setup(c => c.GetOrAddAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<Task<string>>>(), It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>())).ReturnsAsync("latestVersion");`

The error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: c =>
> c.GetOrAddAsync(It.IsAny(),
> It.IsAny<Func<Task>>(), It.IsAny()) Extension
> methods (here: AppCacheExtensions.GetOrAddAsync) may not be used in
> setup / verification expressions.

Then I have come up with another solution which is creating a new instance of MockCachingService():

`var mockedCache = new MockCachingService(); var cacheMock = Mock.Get(mockedCache);`

But I got another type of error

> System.ArgumentException : Object instance was not created by Moq.
> (Parameter 'mocked')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mock extensions, you'll need to mock the interface member that is invoked in the extension. You'll need to inspect it but guessing it'll be one of the following:

```
Task<T> GetOrAddAsync<T>(string key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<T>> addItemFactory);
Task<T> GetOrAddAsync<T>(string key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<T>> addItemFactory, MemoryCacheEntryOptions policy);
```

Source: https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/blob/master/LazyCache/IAppCache.cs

Probably the second one:

```
_cacheMock.Setup(c => c.GetOrAddAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<ICacheEntry, Task<string>>>(), It.IsAny<MemoryCacheEntryOptions>())).ReturnsAsync("latestVersion");
```

The mock caching service included in the library is not a Moq mock, it's closer to a fake implementation. That's why `Mock.Get` won't work on it.

Alternatively, the [unit testing wiki entry](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/wiki/Unit-testing-code-using-LazyCache) covers alternative usages that may suit e.g., use the real thing. For tests using the latter, I use the following to clear the cache after every test:

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
   var cacheProvider = CachingService.CacheProvider;
   var memoryCache = (MemoryCache) cacheProvider.GetType().GetField("cache", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(cacheProvider);
   memoryCache.Compact(1.0);
}
```

If you wish to continue mocking the caching service, the library [LazyCache.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/LazyCache.Testing) (disclaimer: I am the author) offers easy ready to go implementations for Moq and NSubstitute that'll allow you to assert invocations.